# Exception handling does not work correctly, OnExceptionInMainLoop is not called

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets

I updated my environment building wxWidgets2.8.12 with the current version of mingw/msys (gcc 4.8.1)

I used the configure script to build wx-widgets:

```
./configure --prefix=/wx  --with-opengl --enable-debug --enable-debug_gdb --enable-unicode
```

My application relies on the handling of some Exceptions using `wxApp::OnExceptionInMainLoop` in my subclass of `wxApp`. 
This was working fine using mingw gcc 3.4.5 and wxWidgets2.8.7 (prebuilt by wxPack)

Using the new build wxWidgets library, whenever a exception is thrown and not caught directly the program shows a "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" Window and exits with code 3

The except example provided with wxWidgets 2.8.12 (`wxWidgets-2.8.12\samples\except`) shows the same faulty behavior

I tried different versions of wxWidgets (static, release, monolithic) all with the same result.

Basic cross-library exception support in mingw seems to be ok, i verified this using this short test [test](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/issues/detail?id=2)

I would be most grateful for any useful hint, 
or even if somebody could verify my problem (just build the "except" sample in your installation, and select `Throw unhandled exception`)

Comment: btw. this is not the first time i try to solve this issue, i posted in the wx Forum some time ago, sadly without getting any responses: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30350&p=130265&hilit=onExceptionInMainLoop#p130265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SJLJ (and not Dwarf) version of the compiler for the exceptions to propagate correctly from the Windows message handlers, so I think your problem is simply due to using a wrong version.

Comment: Thanks! I used a sjlj version of mingw-gcc 4.8.1 provided by [mingwbuilds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) and now everything works just fine.